# Split the [behavior] Tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I think we need to split the behavior tag into what I've seen are the two common uses for it:

**behavior** - explain behavior of a pet

and

**unwanted-behavior** - refers to an undesirable behavior of a pet

Yes / No / Maybe / Abstain?

Comment: The same as with dogs and cats tags, there just is some tags that get used a lot.

Answer (score 8):

My sense is that every new visitor to the site, along with many regulars, would still select the behavior tag when talking about undesirable behavior, making the split a burden of work for the more active amongst us. That would also negate the value of the second tag since many wouldn't think to look for it.

I guess I don't see the gain with that, so I'd have to vote no on it. :)

Comment: It simply feels that behavior is so broad that most questions are tagged with it.  If it was phrased `behavior` and `behavior-undesired`, or `behavior-innate`, they might be easier to locate in a tag display.

Comment: @JoshDM - I see where you're coming from, but I really suspect that we'd be fighting the tide on that one. It's naturally what people will gravitate to.

Comment: Putting it another way, this feels like we're (attempting to) splitting a tag (arbitrarily) because the list of questions is getting too long. I don't think this will successfully define a different tag space.