# What should we tag questions where a pet is doing an action that the asker wants stopped?

Tags: discussion, retagging

Related to [Split the [behavior] Tag?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/690/split-the-behavior-tag) , but not specific to splitting the behavior tag.  This is a more thought-out proposal, with backing evidence.

Someone asks a question about stopping or preventing a behavior or action.  It inevitably gets tagged either or both "behavior" and "training".

There are **general** questions about animal **behavior**.

- [Why is my one dog's hobby chewing my other dog's fur?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2337/why-is-my-one-dogs-hobby-chewing-my-other-dogs-fur)
- [Can cats get depressed?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/can-cats-get-depressed)
- [Is blinking slowly at cats a way to tell them that you love them?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2281/blinking-slowly-at-a-cat-is-a-way-of-saying-that-you-love-them)

There are **general** questions about **training** (includes "trick training", which is not its own tag):

- [Is corporal punishment an effective training method for dogs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2174/is-corporal-punishment-an-effective-training-method-for-dogs)
- [How do I crate train an adult dog?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/how-do-i-crate-train-an-adult-dog)
- [How hard will it be to train my parrot to talk?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/151/how-hard-will-it-be-to-train-my-parrot-to-talk)
- [How to train a kitten to climb tail-first down a tall climbing tree?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/how-to-train-a-kitten-to-climb-tail-first-down-a-tall-climbing-tree)
- [What should I start with when training a cat to do tricks?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/what-should-i-start-with-when-training-a-cat-to-do-tricks)

We have **toilet-training**

- [How to train a dog to poo in a particular part of the garden?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/94/how-to-train-a-dog-to-poo-in-a-particular-part-of-the-garden)
- [How do I begin toilet training a cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2320/how-do-i-begin-toilet-training-a-cat)

We have **leash-training** (one example of many)

- [How to leash train a rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/677/how-to-leash-train-a-rabbit)

And there are questions intended to stop or prevent a behavior.  They tend to be tagged both "behavior" and "training".  These regard non-existent tag **behavioral-training**:

- [How can I train my cat to not jump on the kitchen counters?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/281/how-can-i-train-my-cat-to-not-jump-on-the-kitchen-counters)
- [How can I train a dog to behave with a cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/483/how-can-i-train-a-dog-to-not-misbehave-with-a-cat)
- [How can I train my guinea pigs to not attack one another?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/130/how-can-i-train-my-guinea-pigs-to-not-attack-one-another)
- [How do I train a puppy not to bite?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/213/how-do-i-train-a-puppy-not-to-bite)
- [How do I get my dog to stop stealing socks?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2307/how-do-i-get-my-dog-to-stop-stealing-socks)

I think creating a "behavioral-training" (or similar; "training-behavior") tag and removing "behavior" and "training" tags from these questions (unless truly needed to embellish them) would help properly classify these "how do I stop this behavior" questions.

Yes / no / maybe / abstain / cowboyneal?

Comment: I like this more. I'm still a little on the fence about what's general training and what's behavioral-training. I like the idea of behavioral training, but it's a very fuzzy border for me between the two.

Comment: Of the general training examples, "corporal punishment" is about training in general, "How do I crate" is not behavioral (you're not training out a bad behavior), "How hard ... parrot" is asking about difficulty, "kitten to climb" and "training a cat to do tricks" are tricks.  The ones under behavioral are elimination of negative behaviors.

Comment: I think "want to understand this confusing behaviour" and "want to stop this undesired behaviour" are distinct enough (and each, individually, large enough) to warrant different tags. I'm not sure what you would call those tags though to make it clear.

Comment: I agree training is way too large but the different types will come as the experts in those training areas come. How about unwanted - behavior?

Comment: I would consider house-training, but that may get confused with toilet/litter training. It strikes me, though, that it's about socialization still and that's a form of general training. I don't really have an answer, but if people wouldn't naturally select a tag, then having it makes it a burden and the value becomes suspect.

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed the tag wiki for [training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training) is:

> Training includes correcting problematic behavior and teaching a pet new behavior or habits.

Would that suggest that the proper tag we would use is the training tag, not the behavior tag?

Comment: Or alternatively, would we need to update the training tag?